# LuaLaTeX and Lucida OTF

Tags: luatex, lucida

I just installed the new Version of the Lucida OpenType fonts which has been released some days ago. Compiling the lucidaot.tex file, which is part of the package with XeLaTeX is no problem. But compiling with LuaLaTeX is a mess, because it never finished. I asked Karl Berry about this and he also saw the "infinite loop" problem with lualatex.

I am running TeXLive2016,  LuLaTeX Version 0.95.0, I rebuild the database with luaotfload-tool --update --force without any success. My operating system is Mac OSX 10.12.2 (Sierra).

Comment: if you think its a latex bug you can contact us by mail (but I don't have the font...)

Comment: David, I don't think it is a LaTeX bug because XeLaTeX has no problem. Based on the answer of Herbert it seems that I have to wait for an update of LuaLaTeX.

Comment: It's a luaotfload problem in 0.95 of LuaTeX. The font database it builds has truncated file names for many fonts so LuaTeX can't find the font. From the answer below it appears that version 1 of LuaTeX has solved that problem.

Comment: @Herb, if this is the reason then I don't understand why there is no fix in texlive2016.

Comment: @Ulrich TeX Live only updates binaries during the freeze, so here TL'16 -> TL'17.

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem with LuaTeX 1.0.1 and `luaotfload.sty` v2.7, 
and `fontspec-luatex.sty` v2.5a and the following preamble for the font setting. Running Linux with the Lucida fonts in my personal directory `~/.fonts/Lucida/`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}  % support opentype math fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=.92}
\setmainfont[% main rm
      ItalicFont=LucidaBrightOT-Italic,
        BoldFont=LucidaBrightOT-Demi,
  BoldItalicFont=LucidaBrightOT-DemiItalic,
  ]{LucidaBrightOT}
%
\setsansfont[% main sans
      ItalicFont=LucidaSansOT-Italic,
        BoldFont=LucidaSansOT-Demi,
  BoldItalicFont=LucidaSansOT-DemiItalic,
  ]{LucidaSansOT}
%
\setmonofont[% main typewriter
      ItalicFont=LucidaSansTypewriterOT-Oblique,
        BoldFont=LucidaSansTypewriterOT-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=LucidaSansTypewriterOT-BoldOblique,
  ]{LucidaSansTypewriterOT}
%
\setmathfont{LucidaBrightMathOT}
\setmathfont[version=bold]{LucidaBrightMathOT-Demibold}
%
% The specialized one-off fonts:
\newfontface\LucidaBlackletter{LucidaBlackletterOT}
\newfontface\LucidaCalligraphy{LucidaCalligraphyOT-Italic}
\newfontface\LucidaHandwriting{LucidaHandwritingOT-Italic}
%
% GrandeMono and Console fonts for an example:
\newfontface\LucidaGrandeMono{LucidaGrandeMonoDK}
\newfontface\LucidaConsole{LucidaConsoleDK}
```

However, at page 7 it needs some time on my system until compilation goes on. The created pdf is here: http://perce.de/pub/lucidaot.pdf

I also have script which copies the relevant parts of luatex from the
ConTeXt minimals into a TeXLive tree. There was a problem in the past with
luaotfload and a error message "wrong luatex version". In the files 
`luaotfload-tool.lua` and `luaotfload-main.lua` the line

```
 luaotfload.min_luatex_version     = { 0, 95, 0 }
```

should be

```
 luaotfload.min_luatex_version     = { 1, 0, 0 }
```

and here is the script. You have to edit the following lines, if needed:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 MINIMAL=/opt/context
 TO=/usr/local/texlive/current
 FROM=$MINIMAL
```

If all that fails, then you can revert everything on TeXLive side with

```
 tlmgr --reinstall install luatex
 tlmgr --reinstall install luaotfload
```

and here is the bash script: http://perce.de/pub/cpCTX2TL.sh

Comment: Herbert, then I have to wait until this version isavailable via the tlmgr update process? Or can I Install this in advance. By the way, with your preamble it is still compiling since  30 minutes.

Comment: @Ulrich There are builds of LuaTeX v1 available but they will not be added to TL'16.

Comment: @Joseph, ok, then I will stay with pdflatex and XeLaTeX. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @Ulrich David C. and I have been running LuaTeX v1+ for some time (W32TeX binaries), as has anyone using MiKTeX. It's also available from the ConTeXt Minimal's set up for Unix systems ...

Comment: @Ulrich: I have a script which copies the needed files from Context minimals into my TeXLive system

Comment: @Herbert, thanks in advance if you send me the script.

Comment: @Ulrich: done with private mail

Comment: @Herbert: I'd like to have the script too, if you don't mind. I suppose one could point tlmgr to the correct repository but I don't know if anyone built x64_darwin binaries for the Mac.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: see edited answer

Comment: @Herbert: That link doesn't work for me.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: You were right, should work now.

Comment: @Herb, since the script is using a linux system, it is unclear for me how to use it on the mac. I have change the 'TO-part x86_64-linux' by 'x86_64_darwin' and the FROM-part 'texmf-linux-64' by 'x86_64-darwin'? What about the 'darwin_universal' subdirectories in parallel. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: @Ulrich: Sorry, but I have no idea what to do on a Mac.

Comment: @Herbert, this was a question for Herb. Maybe somebody can drop me a link where I can look for all this details. Sorry, if this is not the right place to ask such things. Oh I See, HerbSchulz would have been better.

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks for the script. Am I wrong to assume you must have an installed ConTeXt minimal and this script moves items from that installation to TeX Live?

Comment: @HerbSchulz: yes. As an alternative you can get a luatex from https://foundry.supelec.fr/scm/?group_id=10 and compile it yourself. There is also be a tds compatible zipfile of luaotfload https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/releases/download/v2.8-rc3/luaotfload.tds.zip

Comment: @Herbert, if I copy the GitHub content to the TDS  I will have a V1.0 LuaLaTeX? Or do I need more?

Comment: @Ulrich: As far as I remember you need luatex _and_ luaotfload.

Comment: @Herbert, thanks for all the information. I will wait until the new version is part of the official distribution in 2017. Since XeLaTeX is working I can use the Lucida OTF files.