# LuaLateX and TeXLive2017

Tags: lucida

I have just installed TeXLive2017 and I tried to compile the lucidaot.tex file which is part of the actual Lucida package. But I failed with XeLaTeX and LuaLatex. In the first case I got the message "Font-not-found" in the second the compile process never stops. After testing I found that something seems to be wrong with the declaration part of the above mentioned TeX-file.

My result: Calling LucidaBrightOT.otf is not working; without the ending otf everything is ok. Is this known or is this a problem of my local installation?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}  % support opentype math fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=.92}
% this is working ->
\setmainfont[% main rm
  Ligatures=TeX,
  ItalicFont=LucidaBrightOT-Italic.otf,
  BoldFont=LucidaBrightOT-Demi.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=LucidaBrightOT-DemiItalic.otf,
  ]{LucidaBrightOT} 
% <-
%% this is not working: 
%\setmainfont[% main rm
%  Ligatures=TeX,
%      ItalicFont=LucidaBrightOT-Italic.otf,
%        BoldFont=LucidaBrightOT-Demi.otf,
%  BoldItalicFont=LucidaBrightOT-DemiItalic.otf,
%  ]{LucidaBrightOT.otf} <<-- ??
\begin{document}
Test Test
\end{document}
```

See also [LuaLaTeX and Lucida OTF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349856/lualatex-and-lucida-otf) where I asked a similar question.

Comment: Works for me. I'd specify `Extension=.otf` and not type it in for every font, but it's just personal preference.

Comment: @egreg while both version of Ulrich work for me too, I see a pause for the "non-working" version and a message on the terminal "luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: "File not found: LucidaBrightOT.otf.otf."". The source of the problem seems to be the `lucidabrightot.fontspec` which contains `UprightFont = "LucidaBrightOT.otf"` and this is problematic (https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/291). Adding an empty `lucidabrightot.fontspec` in the document folder avoided the problem for me.

Comment: @Ulrike, thanks for the remark. I just installed the fontspec-files coming with the Lucida package without changing them. Now deleting the Extension OTF everything works fine.